# metro shows currentlyFocusedField is deprecated and will be removed in the future

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

[image]

As shown in title and this picture, what should i do with this? i am not using any code from currentlyFocusedField.

I am using:
react native version: 0.63
metro version: 0.59
react navigation/native version: 5.7.0

I am able to run my app but i am not sure if it will show error in production mode. My app is currently in development mode.

Comment: I also face this issue. https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/pull/8365 looks like issue is solved